# Guess a Random Number in 6 trials or less. Not even running

Tags: python-3.x

```
import random
from random import randint
print('Hi, what is your name')
name=input()
print(name + 'Let\'s play a game of guessing a number between 1 and 20')
      
number=random.randint(1,20)
Guesses = 0
print( name + 'please guess a number')
Number =input()      
while Guesses <6:
      if number != Number:
            print('Wrong, please try again')
            Number=input()
            Guesses +=1
```

I am not even getting output, not even an error message. Just an (*) that does not disappear with time.

Comment: Be careful posting your code.  Copying it as is gives an indentation error and there are other syntax errors and indentation errors beyond that.  Paste your exact code, highlight all lines and press the `{}` button to format it as code.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: Thank you for the input. Just rewrote and corrected. This time it runs. Mayhave been a Jupyter bug.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
from random import randint
name=input('What is your name')
print(name + 'Let \'s play a game of guessing a number between 1 and 20 ')
number=random.randint(1,20)
guesses=0

while guesses <= 6:
    guess=input(name + 'please enter a number')
    if number == int(guess):
       print('You got it' + name )
       break
    else:
       print ('Please try again')
       guesses +=1
```

Comment: Please use 4 spaces as 1 indention. Python is sensitive to indentation.

Comment: Explain your solution to the OP.  It's incorrect by the way, but I'll leave you to test it.